# RAII-like action in makefile rule

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to find a good way to add some RAII-like actions into a makefile I'm maintaining. Currently, I have something similar to this:

```
out: in
   lockfile in.lock
   echo in // Some action which can fail
   rm -f in.lock
```

This code works fine when using multiple jobs, as it is mainly meant sanity instead of performance. At least, if my action is not failing. So if I like to add a fallback to this. So in short, it'll look something like:

```
out: in
    lockfile in.lock
    (echo in) || (rm -f in.lock; false)
    rm -f in.lock
```

Yet again looking good, though I don't like having to write twice `rm -f in.lock`, nor does the `(echo in)` looks elegant if the actual content is several lines of bash-script.

This would look similar to:

```
out: in
    lockfile in.lock
    trap "rm -f in.lock" EXIT;           \
    (echo in)
```

However, this would make the actual rules look more complex if you have different rules which are really separate.

```
out: in
    lockfile in.lock
    trap "rm -f in.lock" EXIT;           \
    $(SHOW_DEPENDENCY_ON_DEBUG)      &&  \
    (echo in)
```

Where SHOW_DEPENDENCY_ON_DEBUG can be defined as `echo $@ <=== $^` in certain circumstances and `@` in others. So I'm not that sure if I can nicely chain all commands. Therefore I hope any of you know of some tricks that I've missed.

In short, I like to transform:

```
out: in
    lockfile in.lock
    echo in // Some action(s) which can fail
    rm -f in.lock
```

In a way that always executes `rm -f in.lock`, without having to chain bash-commands or duplicating the action(s) that have to be executed to finalize the actions in the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the problem of ensuring the your lockfile (or any file that `make` makes) is deleted come what may,
`make` has a stock solution: make it an [`.INTERMEDIATE` target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html).
Then, if `make` creates the file, it will auto-delete it at the end, come what may, e.g.

**Makefile**

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: out

in:
    touch $@ # Whatever

.INTERMEDIATE: in.lock

%.lock: %
    touch $@ # Whatever

out: in.lock
    if [ "`shuf -i 0-1 -n 1`" = "0" ]; then echo Fail; false ; else echo Succeed; touch $@; fi
    rm -f $<

clean:
    rm -f in out
```

Here the command:

```
if [ "`shuf -i 0-1 -n 1`" = "0" ]; then echo Fail; false ; else echo Succeed; touch $@; fi
```

will fail or succeed on a pseudo-random coin-toss.

Some runs:

```
$ make
touch in # Whatever
touch in.lock # Whatever
if [ "`shuf -i 0-1 -n 1`" = "0" ]; then echo Fail; false ; else echo Succeed; touch out; fi
Succeed
rm -f in.lock
$ make clean
rm -f in out  
$ make
touch in # Whatever
touch in.lock # Whatever
if [ "`shuf -i 0-1 -n 1`" = "0" ]; then echo Fail; false ; else echo Succeed; touch out; fi
Fail
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'out' failed
make: *** [out] Error 1
rm in.lock
```

But don't push this feature so far as removing the

```
rm -f $<
```

from the recipe. `make` will delete the intermediates *at exit*, which is fine if the recipe fails.
But if the recipe succeeds you presumably want the lockfile deleted right away rather than when
`make` finishes, which might be arbitrarily later.

**Later**

> Any chance the .INTERMEDIATE can refer to wildcard, like %.lock?

No. You'd have to mean:

```
.INTERMEDIATE: %.lock
```

and there is no "wildcard" there. With no `%` in lefthand side,
it's not a pattern-rule and `%` in the righthand side only just means `%`.

But you don't need this. You must know the names of the prerequisites you
want to lock or at least be able to compute them with [`make`functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Functions.html).
Otherwise you can't write the makefile at all. So say they are `ina inb inc`.
Then you make all the locks intermediate like:

```
inputs := ina inb inc
locks := $(patsubst %,%.lock,$(inputs))

.INTERMEDIATE: $(locks)
```

Comment: Any chance the .INTERMEDIATE can refer to wildcard, like %.lock?

Comment: I know that trick, ain't that simple in my case, though I guess a few building blocks will be able to get something working. Why can't it every be easy? Tnx anyhow!